# Process mail bursts one at a time

Tags: perl, email, sendmail, procmail

we receive bursts of mails from our IDS that we are postprocessing to create incident reports, forward them to request tracker, etc. Right now, we have one script that does all the postprocessing that is called by procmail according to rules in /etc/aliases. Something like:

ids-report: "|/opt/ids/process.pl"

Now, the problem is that running many instances of this script because of mail bursts can lead to memory depletion and some synchronization nastyness.

In my script, I tried using [Sys::RunAlone](http://search.cpan.org/~elizabeth/Sys-RunAlone-0.12/lib/Sys/RunAlone.pm), but found it suboptimal.

I would like procmail to feed my script one mail from queue at a time, but I have not found a way to do it.

Do you guys have any idea, what could I do? Out-of-the-box solutions are welcomed too...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second [Georgi Rangelov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27359539/874188) but if you are seriously asking how to run only one message at a time in Procmail, the answer is to use a lock file.

```
:0:only1.lock
| /opt/ids/process.pl
```

This means, if the file `only1.lock` exists, wait.  Once it's gone, create it, run the pipe, and then remove the lock file when done.

See also http://porkmail.org/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be closest to what I have in mind. I am just wondering if there is some issue with this solution (e.g., performance).

Comment: Yes, serializing something which used to be parallel will make it take more time. As long as you can finish the queue before the next burst on average, you should not end up with congestion. If you can't, maybe you can figure out how to minimize the critical section -- maybe modularize the script into smaller scripts, most of which can be run in parallel, or handle the locking inside the script using some Perl mutex mechanism. Or prepare to buy more hardware, or lose some messages.

Answer (score 4):

Why not save every mail to a file or database as soon as you receive them and process the saved records one at a time from another script ?

If you post some code you may receive more (and possibly better) answers :)

Comment: That's what we use at my workplace for a monitoring solution. Procmail puts incoming alert mails in a queue, and a daemon watches over the queue directory, spawning workers to handle the mails.

Comment: I wanted to avoid another database indirection. Incoming mail is saved until it is delivered. So it is already a database of some sort and I wanted to use it. tripleee's answer is probably closest to what I want. But if it's not going to work, I will have to resort to another database layer.

I am afraid I am not able to post the code. Especially those bottlenecks that are causing my problems are highly dependent on our infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

### "IMAP with idle" mailbox as buffer/pipeline of email messages

You may deliver messages to IMAP mailbox.  You can use `fetchmail` with --idle (to get real time processing) and --mda (to execute your script).

You can make `procmail` deliver messages to maildir as use `dovecot` **even without daemon running** to allow `fetchmail` access maildir using IMAP protocol.

P.S. I may provide a few more details if you are interested.  AFAIR I had used it to handle spams catched by my spamtrap server.

Comment: Interesting solution. If the above fails me, I will definitely try it and get back to you later.